# Google Chrome won't show font (css3, wordpress) first time visiting. (only on refresh)

Tags: wordpress, css, fonts

Fonts won't show the first time I visit the site (only in Google Chrome).

[www.iphonereparaturkiel.de](http://www.iphonereparaturkiel.de)

Any ideas why this is occuring?

Comment: This could be a bug in Chrome, Does this work in other browsers?

Comment: I see the same behavior with Chrome. Firefox does not have the problem, and neither does IE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Embedded Fonts Render Then Disappear](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21241425/embedded-fonts-render-then-disappear)

Comment: Look at this: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=236298 It's a bug with Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

This bug was present in M31 and M32, but was fixed in M33.  I checked your site and it looks like it has been resolved. You should mark this answered.  Info about it can be found at the link Kees Sonnenema provided [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=236298) as well as a few other places.